# XPath to join all resulting nodes with string separator

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to join the values of all the nodes that match an expression and have them separated by a comma. For example, the following xml should return "num1,num2,num3"

```
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <other>y</other>
    <notarget>x</notarget>
    <target>num1</target>
    <target>num2</target>
    <target>num3</target>
  </product>
</products>
```

The XPath `/*[name()='products']/*[name()='product']/*[name()='target']` should get the elements, but I just don't understand how to join them.

Comment: If you're using xpath 2.0, you could use `string-join()` - for your input  `string-join(//target,',')` results in `num1,num2,num3`

Comment: @matthias_h I'm not using xpath 2.0

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think in xpath 1.0 it's only possible if you know the number of elements and then use `concat()`, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373041/return-text-from-several-elements-in-one-string-using-xpath

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath to return string concatenation of qualifying child node values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403971/xpath-to-return-string-concatenation-of-qualifying-child-node-values) or [Return text from several elements in one string using xPath](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17373041/290085)

Comment: @kjhughes based on those answers, would the path be /*[name()='products']/*[name()='product']/*[name()='target']/text() and then concatenate on my own? I'm asking because it doesn't seem to be providing all the nodes

Comment: First, use `/products/product/target/text()` rather than that convoluted predicate pattern you're using.  Second, as the other answers indicate, if you have a fixed number of `target` elements, you can select each and `concat()` them together; otherwise, yes, select them and then join them together outside of XPath if you can't use XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done in pure XPath 1.0 without some help from the host language. In fact it's difficult even with help from the host language, because XPath 1.0 has no concept of a "sequence of strings".

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:value-of select="[set of nodes]" separator="."/>
```

I wanted to do the same thing and solved it with the separator attribute using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="/products/product/target">
  <xsl:if test="position() != 1">,</xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You can place it inside variable if you want to reuse it later:

```
<xsl:variable name="concat">
  <xsl:for-each select="products/product/target">
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1">,</xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$concat"/>
```

Comment: This would be a great answer if the question were about xslt rather than xpath...

Comment: My fault. If it's a saxon or xalan then it's rather easy to write external funtion that will return concatenated strings.

Answer (score 0):

With [saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) :

```
saxon-lint --output-separator , --xpath '//target/text()' file
```

#### OUTPUT

```
num1,num2,num3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat` with your delimiter (per https://stackoverflow.com/a/25766054/148889)

```
concat(//SomeElement/text(),'_',//OtherElement/text())
```