# XPath concat same tagname

Tags: java, xpath, java1.4

I'm trying with this attempt to produce an xml based on the one given, joining values of same TagName.
For example this is what I've done so far:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class TestXPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException {
         String xml =
                    "<ROOT>" +
                    "    <coolnessId>9</coolnessId>" +
                    "    <cars id=\"3\">0</cars>" +
                    "    <cars id=\"2\">1</cars>" +
                    "    <cars id=\"1\">2</cars>" +
                    "</ROOT>";

                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

                Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
                XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

               ///XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("concat(//ROOT/cars,'-',//ROOT/coolnessId)");//concat(//ROOT/cars)
                XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("concat(//ROOT/cars,'-')");//concat(//ROOT/cars)
                // XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile( "concat(//*[contains(name(), 'cars')],'')");
            System.out.println(expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING)); 
    }
}
```

This code produces:

```
0-
```

Now this is what should be:

```
2-1-0
```

As you can see the values follow the attribute "id" of each "cars" tag.
I've rearrenged many times but can't achieve my result.
Please keep in mind I'm on a very old enviroment such as Java 1.4 runtime.

Comment: See [here for XPath 1.0 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373041/how-to-return-text-from-several-elements-in-one-string-using-xpath). In XPath 2.0 you could use string-join instead of concat.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's going to be simplest to retrieve the nodes using XPath, and then concatenate the string values in Java code.

Any other solution involves upgrading your technology: XSLT, XPath 2.0+, etc, and that isn't going to be easy on a JDK 1.4 platform.